# Google Checkout Notification API Python Example

Tags: python, django, google-checkout

Currently, there are absolutely no code snippets of the Notification API in Python. I am currently at a loss as the documentation, as thorough as it is, seems to be missing important information necessary to actually code a solution for myself.

Currently, I have a single product that I wish to submit to Google Checkout along with a hidden item, which would be the userid of the user currently logged into my site. Upon payment completion, the callback URL will receive the information, and process the user's payment information (serial key, order number, userid) and update the database.

I am using Django.

Gchecky is there, but it doesn't seem to work - and I've attempted multiple times to get a hold of the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Chippy's Shop:

http://code.google.com/p/chippysshop/

http://code.google.com/p/chippysshop/source/browse/googlecheckout.py